# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: DexException: Multiple dex files define -- Hamcrest

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error when I run a method from under the androidTest directory. I'm currently attempting to test out Espresso UI testing, and I encounter the error depicted below.

I've looked at other similar questions on Stack Overflow, and according to their answers, it seems that there are duplicated classes. I am not entirely sure which classes are duplicated; I tried searching for MatcherAssert specifically (shown by the fourth picture), but since I'm new to Android, I'm not entirely sure if there are supposed to be all three of hamcrest-core, integration, and library. There are probably other conflicts as well, but I would really appreciate any guidance on what duplicates there are.

I am currently using buildToolsVersion 21.1.2. Regarding the "non-zero exit value 2," I tried adding

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

[image: The error report]

[image: External Libraries]

[image: Dependencies]

[image: Search for duplicates]

Comment: I don't know this library, but you sure you need both hamcrest-integration and hamcrest-library?

Comment: I've been looking at ways to exclude the library in build.gradle without actually removing the specific external library, is there a way do that?

Comment: If they are in conflict they might be redundant. Have you tried excluding one of them? It seems both hamcrest-core and hamcrest-integration have the same class, which means you should delete one. They are not included through your build.gradle file.

Comment: I just tried removing the other two hamcrest libraries, and the same error comes up even though MatcherAssert is only displayed once--there must be something else that's an error. I'm trying to remove the support-annotations-21.0.3 because 22.2.0 is there, but it's not under the MainApp.iml file.

Comment: Try removing both integration and library, leaving only hamcrest-core. Clean your project and try to build it again. If it doesn't work then I don't know how to help anymore

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, I'm going to look around for some other solutions, but thank you for all the help!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more, and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is now fixed.

What I did was I removed

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
```

from build.gradle, and updated Espresso from 2.1 to 2.2.

I realized I did not add Instrumentation Registry within my Espresso test case, so I added that per the official Android development website.

After that I invalidated caches (File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart), restarted and then cleaned and rebuilt everything. I ran the test case, the error no longer occurred.

I do not fully understand what caused the error, but due to the above steps, now it gets past the past roadblock.