# Gradle - DexException: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dex

I know this question has been asked already but I cannot find a suitable answer for my problem among the available solutions. I hope you guys can help me out.

The exception tells that `Multiple dex files defined` and I tried several common ways to fix this problem. Unfortunately, this didn't help.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2



Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lnet/jcip/annotations/GuardedBy;
        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lnet/jcip/annotations/GuardedBy;
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
            at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

1. **I tried to clean and rebuild the project.**

   - Build -> Clean Project
   - Build -> Rebuild Project
2. **Then I tried to Invalidate Caches and Restart.**

   - File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart
3. **I also run this command to understand the duplications in dependencies:**

   > ./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile --stacktrace

and here is the output. As you can see there are no duplications.

```
+--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.1
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1
|    +--- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1
+--- com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.0
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.0
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.1
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.1
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.1.2
|         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.2.0 -> 1.3.1
+--- com.greenhalolabs:emailautocompletetextview:1.3.0
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
+--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.2.0
|    +--- com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-annotations:1.2.0 -> 1.2.1
|    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.5
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.0
+--- io.keen:keen-client-api-android:2.1.2
+--- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:6.3.1
+--- net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:3.0.6
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
+--- com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0
+--- com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1
+--- com.ouralabs:ouralabs:2.7.0
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.1
+--- project :domain
|    \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.0
\--- project :remote
     +--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
     +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0
     |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.4.0
     \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0
```

4. **I also read about the `multiDexEnabled true` but I'm sure that I didn't exceed the methods limit. This issue appeared instantly and without adding any libraries. I even can't assemble the older production versions of the code. They are in production and absolutely compilable.**

Module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    compile "com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:${rootProject.ext.activeandroid}"
    compile(group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'annotations', version: "${rootProject.ext.findbugs}") {
        exclude(group: 'net.jcip', module: 'jcip-annotations')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.android.support', name: 'appcompat-v7', version: "${rootProject.ext.supportv4}") {
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android', name: 'crashlytics', version: "${rootProject.ext.crashlytics}") {
        exclude(group: 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android', module: 'answers')
    }
    compile "com.greenhalolabs:emailautocompletetextview:${rootProject.ext.emailautocomplete}"
    compile(group: 'com.facebook.android', name: 'facebook-android-sdk', version: "${rootProject.ext.facebook}") {
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4')
    }
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportv4}"
    compile "com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:${rootProject.ext.hugo}"
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:${rootProject.ext.jodatime}"
    compile "io.keen:keen-client-api-android:${rootProject.ext.keen}"
    compile "com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:${rootProject.ext.libphonenumber}"
    compile "net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:${rootProject.ext.menudrawer}"
    compile "com.squareup:otto:${rootProject.ext.otto}"
    compile(group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-base', version: "${rootProject.ext.playservices}") {
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-analytics', version: "${rootProject.ext.playservices}") {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement')
    }
    compile(group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-gcm', version: "${rootProject.ext.playservices}") {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement')
    }
    compile "com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:${rootProject.ext.slidingmenu}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportv4}"
    compile "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${rootProject.ext.timber}"
    compile "com.viewpagerindicator:library:${rootProject.ext.viewpagerindicator}"
    compile "com.ouralabs:ouralabs:${rootProject.ext.ouralabs}"
    compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"

    compile project(':domain')
    compile(project(':remote')) {
        exclude module: 'domain'
    }

    // Local Unit testing
    testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junit"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$rootProject.ext.hamcrestVersion"

    // Instrumentation Testing
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:$rootProject.ext.uiautomator"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion"
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:$rootProject.ext.dexmaker"
    androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:$rootProject.ext.dexmaker"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I checked the project for `GuardedBy`. Is it looks like duplication?

[image]

Comment: It happens because you are adding more net/jcip/annotations/GuardedBy classes. Check your jar files.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti but how to exclude this duplication? Can you write an answer, please?

Comment: I am trying to understand your issue. First of all check if you are using these jars in the libs folder or if you are getting them from other libraries. The problem may be is that you are using different version of the same class.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I don't use the 'libs' folder. I think, they are from other libraries.

Comment: perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/31083982/794088 might lead to whats going wrong

Comment: @petey but I don't have the library from this answer in my build.gradle. Unfortunately, this answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `hugo-annotations` is included twice.  It's a dependency of `hugo-runtime` and added from somewhere else.  Try excluding it from the `hugo-runtime`

```
compile("com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:${rootProject.ext.hugo}") {
    exclude(group: 'com.jakewharton.hugo' module: 'hugo-annotations')
}
```

Also since the error is due to the jsr library may need to exclude it from the `findbugs` dependency.

```
compile(group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'annotations', version: "${rootProject.ext.findbugs}") {
    exclude(group: 'net.jcip', module: 'jcip-annotations')
    exclude(group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305')
}
```

Edit:

There is a nuclear option if you really can't find it, but I'm not sure if it would break something else or is best practice.  This removes `jsr305` from the classpath completely.

```
dependencies {
    ...
}
configurations.all*.exclude module: 'jsr305'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same exception. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You can try the edit but that may have adverse affects on the tooling when findbugs runs

Answer (score 0):

Check your jar files. You can expand the files in the project explorer.
If it has unnecessary path and BuildConfig, DexException should be occured.